# Refreshing Fragment ListView using custom ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.
I have searched the web for an answer to my issue, but have not found anything that would help.

I have a ListView and a CustomViewAdapter within a Fragment. This works fine. The list is displayed correctly.

What I have a problem with is if a row within the list changes, although the row gets updated, the actual list does not. To put it in context, what I have is a list of favorites and they are shown in a favorites fragment. However, if the user "unfavorites" an item, even though the icon that shows it is a favorite change, the actual list still shows that item, rather than refresh the list and remove that item from the list.

As I said, I have tried all the solutions I could find related to this issue, such as calling notifyDataSetChanged with the adapter.

My code in the fragment:

```
public void ShowFavourites(){
    globalVariable = ((GlobalClass) getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    JCDatabaseHelper helper = new JCDatabaseHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    ArrayList<ArticleItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArticleItem myItem1;
    String[] columnNames = {"_id", "Column1", "Column2", "Column3",
            "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7"};
    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id",
            "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7" });
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.imageButton, R.id.title, R.id.year, R.id.authors,
            R.id.favs, R.id.read, R.id.readOnLine};
    final ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayList<Favourites> favouritesArrayList = helper.GetFavourites();
     for (Favourites articleItem : favouritesArrayList) {
          // code to access items
          //then...
          matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{k, imgFile,Title, Year , Authors, favIcon , btn1.getText(), btn2.getText() });
          myItem1 = new ArticleItem(ID, Title, Year);
          rowItems.add(myItem1);
     }
    CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter;
    ListView yourListView;
    customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.article_row, rowItems);
    yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The code in CustomListViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleItem> {

  ArrayList<ArticleItem> _rowItems;
  ArticleItem item;
  View row;

  public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             ArrayList<ArticleItem> articleItems) {
    super(context, resourceId,articleItems);
    this.context = context;
    _rowItems = articleItems;
    }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    row = convertView;
    item = _rowItems.get(position);
    if (row == null) {
       LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_row, parent, false);
    }

    // other code to set TextViews, etc ...
    final int FavYes = R.drawable.favourite;
    final int FavNo = R.drawable.favourite_outline;

    final ImageButton favBtn = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.favs);
    if (Favs.equals("Y")){
        favBtn.setImageResource(FavYes);
    }
    else favBtn.setImageResource(FavNo);

    favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        JCDatabaseHelper helper = new JCDatabaseHelper(getContext());
            item = _rowItems.get(position);
            ID = item.getID();
            Title = item.getTitle();
            String NewFavs;
            if (Favs.equals("N")){
                NewFavs = "Y";
                favBtn.setImageResource(FavYes);
                helper.UpdateFavourite("FavouritesTable", ID, NewFavs);
            }
            else {
                NewFavs = "N";
                favBtn.setImageResource(FavNo);
                helper.UpdateFavourite("FavouritesTable", ID, NewFavs);
                // THIS ACTION SHOULD TAKE THIS ROW FROM THE LIST AND RESHOW THE LIST. 
            }
     }
    });

 return row;
}
```

I have tried the following answers:
1. [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview) but it doesn't work. Maybe because I don't call it correctly.
2. [notifyDataSetChanged() in Fragment is not refreshing listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494478/notifydatasetchanged-in-fragment-is-not-refreshing-listview) 
Other questions/answers were dealing with similar, but not the same issue.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() from inside the starIconClickListener inside getView(), so everytime the star change you tell the adapter it should recreate all the views because the data inside them has changed. Youre calling it after setAdapter(), remove that call is unnecesary :)

Comment: How you are getting **Favs** value which you are using in if loop..?

Comment: @marcos Thank you, Yes, I realise the call is useless! How would I call it inside the customListViewAdapter?

Comment: Are you really running this code? I can see as minimum one NPE

Comment: @Stanislav, this is a summary of the code. I don't get any NPE.

Comment: @Muthukrishan, the call for Favs:         final String Favs = helper.getValueFromTable("FavouritesTable", "ID", ID, "favourite");
I have not shown it in the code snippet above, sorry.

Comment: `ListView yourListView;` and `yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);` Don't see initilization of `ListView`

Comment: @Stanislav, yes I do initialise it yourListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list); but it is not in the snippet, sorry. Otherwise as you say I would get a NPE.

Comment: could you add **UpdateFavourite** and **getValueFromTable** from your DB in question?

Comment: @Muthukrishnan, apologies, I don't understand your question. The call **UpdateFavourite** and **getValueFromTable** work fine. the database is updated fine.

Comment: Anyway you answered my question, I just asked to check is there any issue there, If you checked already not a problem.

Comment: Create your ArticleItem item as a local value make it final.

Comment: and **View row;**  too

Comment: @Muthukrishnan not sure I understand your suggestions...

Comment: @marcos, would you be able to tell me how to call the notifyDataSetChanged() from within the  'favBtn.setOnClickListener' ? I realise I need to call it there, but don't know how to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the code I think `notifyDataSetChanged` method should be working in this case.

The key point is that you should modify the collection before invoking `notifyDataSetChanged`, since this method is only going to take your collection (`_rowItems`) and inflating every item again into the ListView.
So if the collection still contains that item, that is going to stay in the list.

Since you are setting your `articleItems` to the `_rowItems` field when constructing the adapter, I think the fastest approach could be to call listView.getAdapter().removeItem(itemNotFavorite). Note that to do this you have to cast your adapter to be an `ArrayAdapter` before :)

Another chance, maybe a little cleaner can be to create a setter in the adapter to overwrite your collection, and then rely on `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Let me know if some of this works ;)

Comment: thank you. I think I understand what your suggestions, but obviously not enough as I would not know how to code them. Would you be able to provide some code?

Comment: I think that the `notifyDataSetChanged` should work, but I don't know how to call it from within the CustomListViewAdapter ... would you know how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried what you said, that the notifyDataSetChanged should work. The issue I had was that I was not calling it right or from the right place. I will add what I have done as an answer, in case it helps anyone else, but thank you very much for your explanations. They helped

Comment: @user3079872 I'm Happy that helped! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an answer through Marino's answer, so have marked their answer as the correct one. I just wanted to show the code I added in case it helps anyone else. 
I added the following to the CustomListViewAdapter I am just posting part of the code above)

```
  favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    JCDatabaseHelper helper = new JCDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        item = _rowItems.get(position);
        ID = item.getID();
        Title = item.getTitle();
        String NewFavs;
        if (Favs.equals("N")){
            NewFavs = "Y";
            favBtn.setImageResource(FavYes);
            helper.UpdateFavourite("FavouritesTable", ID, NewFavs);
        }
        else {
            NewFavs = "N";
            favBtn.setImageResource(FavNo);
            helper.UpdateFavourite("FavouritesTable", ID, NewFavs);
            // Here is what helped!
            _rowItems.remove(item); //this removes the item that has been set as no longer a favourite
            CustomListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this I suppose refreshes the adapter
        }
 }
});
```

Thanks also to @Marcos, who gave me a clue on what to do.